# How to kill all background processes in zsh?

Tags: linux, background, zsh, jobs

As in the title - how to kill all background processes in zsh?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```bash
alias killbg='kill ${${(v)jobstates##*:*:}%=*}'
```

. It is zsh, no need in external tools.

If you want to kill job number N:

```bash
function killjob()
{
    emulate -L zsh
    for jobnum in $@ ; do
        kill ${${jobstates[$jobnum]##*:*:}%=*}
    done
}
killjob N
```

Comment: @ZachRiggle It is in `man zshexpn` and `man zshmodules`: `$jobstates` is a associative array parameter, `(v)` selects only values from this array, `#` makes zsh remove given pattern starting from the start of string, selects least lengthy pattern for removal, `*:*:`: pattern that makes zsh remove first two colon-separated fields of each value (`#` on array parameters is applied to each value), `%` is like `#`, but for end of strings and `=*` makes zsh remove everything after the last eq sign including the sign itself. Each `$jobstates` value looks like `job-state:mark:pid=state...`.

Comment: It appears I have a bug here: it does not work if the whole pipe was suspended.

Comment: **Update**: changed `#` to `##`: this way it will remove everything up to the last colon, effectively leaving only last process in the pipe. I am working under an assumption that last one will always be alive, otherwise more complex computations should be performed.

Answer (score 7):

one should use the [`builtin`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) zsh built-in command alongside with the other [`kill`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) zsh built-in command as:

```
builtin kill %1
```

as [`kill`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/kill.c) is also a separate binary **file** from [`util-linux`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux)package ([upstream](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/), [mirror](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux)) located in `/usr/bin/kill` which **does not support jobs** (`kill: cannot find process "%1"`).

use keyword `builtin` to avoid name conflict or [`enable`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) the `kill` built-in if it is disabled.

---

there is a concept of disabling and enabling built-in commands (ie. shell's own commands such as `cd` and `kill` ) in shells, and in [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) you can enable (a disabled) `kill` builtin as:

```
enable kill
```

---

issue `disable` to check if the builtin is disabled (and `enable` to see the enabled ones).

Comment: The question was how to kill **_all_** background processes. If you have 100s, doing it one-by-one ain't gonna cut it, however useful it is to know about this `builtin` vs. file conflict namespace conflict.

Answer (score 2):

Minor adjustment to @Zxy's response...

On my system, I found that suspended jobs weren't killed properly with the default kill signal. I had to actually change it to `kill -KILL` to get `suspended` background jobs to die properly.

```
alias killbg='kill -KILL ${${(v)jobstates##*:*:}%=*}'
```

Pay special attention to the SINGLE QUOTES around this. If you switched to double quotes, you would need to escape the each "$". Note that you can NOT use a `function` to wrap this command since the function will increment the `$jobstates` array causing the function to try killing itself... Must use an alias.

The `killjob` script above is a bit redundant since you can just do:

```
kill %1
```

Less keystrokes and it's already build into `zsh`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for both ZSH and Bash:

```
: '
killjobs - Run kill on all jobs in a Bash or ZSH shell, allowing one to optionally pass in kill parameters

Usage: killjobs [zsh-kill-options | bash-kill-options]

With no options, it sends `SIGTERM` to all jobs.
'
killjobs () {

    local kill_list="$(jobs)"
    if [ -n "$kill_list" ]; then
        # this runs the shell builtin kill, not unix kill, otherwise jobspecs cannot be killed
        # the `$@` list must not be quoted to allow one to pass any number parameters into the kill
        # the kill list must not be quoted to allow the shell builtin kill to recognise them as jobspec parameters
        kill $@ $(sed --regexp-extended --quiet 's/\[([[:digit:]]+)\].*/%\1/gp' <<< "$kill_list" | tr '\n' ' ')
    else
        return 0
    fi

}
```

@zyx answer didn't work for me.

More on it here: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6084a504b6a7fee270670fc8f5887eb4

Comment: Use gsed from brew in macOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias killbg='for job in \`jobs -l | egrep -o "([0-9][0-9]+)"`;
```

Comment: Super! Now try suspending `echo 123 | less` and check out what it will kill. Hint: by the time you run `kill` `echo 123` process will already be dead and its PID may already have been taken. So with such suspended pipe with your `killbg` you may kill 2 innocent processes: process `123` (`echo` argument) and process that happened to retake `echo` PID.

Comment: My solution will fail in this case though (it will try to kill `{echoPID}=done:{lessPID}`).